# Distributed Transaction in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, distributed-transactions

So Exciting that MongoDB 4.0 support Multi-Document ACID Transactions!! But I wondering will the new feature solve my problem?

Background: i have several microservice, they share the same mongdb, so we have to face the transactions problem between them.

example:  A start the transaction then call B service and C service via http, and B will call D. if one of B,C,D failed, we need to rollback. it's hard to reach this goal in this distributed system, so I wondering whether mongodb 4.0 will have the easy way to solve the problem.

  `A
 /  \ 
B    C
 \
  D`

I've readed the specifications from here: https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/transactions/transactions.rst, i found that mongo use lsid, txnNumber to identify a transaction. so, is that mean if I develop a special Mongo-Driver that accept the lsid, txnNumber as parameters to build the special command and this will reach my goal: if one step raise error, rollback everything!

Answer (score 0):

> if one of B,C,D failed, we need to rollback

There are alternatives way to do this without multi-document transactions. You can have a document that gets updated by the processes A, B, C, and D. For example, D marks the document to `completed`.

[MongoDB multi-document transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) is designed for situations that require atomicity for updates to multiple documents or consistency between reads to multiple documents. So, multiple database operations and/or multiple documents as a single transaction. From your description, your use case is more about multiple stages that can progress through or not, this can be handled using appropriate [data modeling](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/).

In addition, please note that there is also a limit for the lifetime of a transaction. The default is 60 seconds. See also [transactionLifetimeLimitSeconds](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/#param.transactionLifetimeLimitSeconds).